# Uninstall marshmallow updates

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, downgrade, moto-x-play

I am using motorola Moto X Play it is shipped with android lollipop 5.0, recently I got notification to update to android marshmallow 6.0, after update I am not able to move applications to memory card and many other issues..

Is there any way to switch back to lollipop?

Please help!

Comment: You'll need to get a Lollipop ROM for your device and flash it, that's the only way do downgrade. There's no such thing as "uninstall updates" for the OS.

Comment: I doubt it will void the warranty, Is it?

Comment: Depends on the ROM. Flashing an "official image" provided by the manufacturer shouldn't void the warranty. Flashing a 3rd party ROM probably will.

Comment: Whether it will void the warranty or not is something we cannot deal with since legal issues are off-topic here. You may want to browse Motorola's website to find out warranty details and related documents to ascertain whether unlocking bootloader or flashing the device would void warranty.

Comment: Sorry, but that cannot be helped. Alternative is approaching support with your issues and having them sort it out – giving them the option to downgrade if everything else fails.

Comment: Please don't remove relevant tags.

Comment: Why it is downgraded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to revert back to Lollipop without rooting your device and using a custom lollipop ROM.

If you're not familiar with rooting see: http://theunlockr.com/2015/09/21/root-motorola-moto-x-play/